# Is it possible to publish story and upload photo to Facebook feed without dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to publish a story to someone's Facebook feed and upload an image (if I have the permissions to do so - obviously) without showing the user the Facebook dialog window? Maybe using the Graph API?

I want this to happen behind the scenes once the user press the "Share" button in my app.

Notice that this is a client only app - no server on the other side.

Comment: It would be nice if you did a little bit of research before asking here. You would easily find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.It is possible. You can user Graph API for that.

You can use the below code :

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                  andParams:params
                            andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                              andDelegate:self];
```

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!